# Problema con clearTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Quiero paralizar el `setTimeout` con `clearTimeout` pero no hay manera.
El código es el siguiente:

```
function limpiarModal(){
    $("#ventana-emergente").animate({top:"-350px"},1000);
    set=setTimeout(function(){$("#ventana-modal").css("visibility","hidden")}, 1000);
    $("body").removeClass("clase-modal-body");
    $("#ingresar-nav").css('cursor', 'pointer');
    clearTimeout(set);
}
```

El tema es que quiero que `$("#ventana-modal)` se oculte al cabo de un 1 segundo y con `clearTimeout` "limpiar" la acumulación del `setTimeout`.

Comment: Lo curioso es que si el clearTimeout lo escribo como **clearTimeOut** me sale error en consola pero ejecuta bien lo que quiero. `function limpiarModal(){
 $("#ventana-emergente").animate({top:"-350px"},1000);
 set=setTimeout(function(){$("#ventana-modal").css("visibility","hidden")}, 1000);
 $("body").removeClass("clase-modal-body");
 $("#ingresar-nav").css('cursor', 'pointer');
 clearTimeOut(set);
}`

Comment: disculpa porque la variable `set` no esta declarada? o no es una ariable?

Comment: el `clearTimeout(set);` esta en la misma función... ósea ni le da tiempo a ejecutar `setTimeout`.. posible solución es quitar simplemente el `clearTimeout()`

Comment: un Timeout se ejecuta una sola vez y no vuelve a suceder, si usas clearTimeout tu ventana de modal no se ocultará, es como si estuvieras confundiendo un Interval con un Timeout

Comment: Era una confusión mía, el problema estaba en `$("#ventana-emergente").animate({top:"-350px"},1000);`. Era lo que me producía la acumulación de tiempo.Muchas gracias por las respuestas.